# The Sunshine vs Sunshine

Tags: definite-article

> Keep your face towards sunshine, and you’ll never have to see the shadow again.

Vs

> Keep your face towards **the** sunshine, and you’ll never have to see the shadow again.

Is ‘the’ necessary in front of the word Sunshine? Because here we’re talking about sunshine in general not a specific sunshine

Comment: Your example simply doesn't strike me as something a native Anglophone would be likely to say. ***Sunshine*** (along with ***sunlight*** and ***daylight***) are normally seen as "omnidirectional" (the light comes from the whole sky, not just the sun). You can only point or move *towards* them if you're currently in a dark enclosed space, and you can see chinks of light from somewhere leading to the open-air outside world. If you're already outside (as implied by casting a shadow), you might turn to ***face to sun***, but you wouldn't ***face the sunshine***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: In my experience, "towards" (or "to", or anything indicating direction) can create an idiosyncratic sense of "sunshine". "To have one's back to the sunshine" is a not uncommon synonym for "to have one's back to the sun". Of course, what's 'correct' according to any standard would potentially be different. "Sunshine" or "sunlight" usually means the light of the sun, and while one can be "in" it, "moving towards" it would usually mean not being in it and moving closer to it.

Comment: @SamBC: You say you're a native speaker, so I'm not sure I can really take issue with what you consider "natural". But I would just point out that Google Books has ***no** written instances* of [*his back to the **sunshine***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22his+back+to+the+sunshine%22), whereas it claims *About **141,000** results* for what I consider the natural version: [*his back to the **sun***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22his+back+to+the+sun%22).

Comment: Thinking about it, I'm pretty sure what I'm talking about there may be mostly in spoken language, rather than written. There's a lot of little differences that crop up - and not consistently - in spoken English versus written. Though not as much of a difference as I'm told theree is between spoken Schweizerdeutsch and written German used in Switzerland.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you must use **the**

According to the Cambridge Dictionary

**[the](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/the)**

> used to refer to things or people when **only one exists at any one time**

We have got **only one** sun shining in the sky.

**[sunshine](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sunshine)**

> the light and heat that come from **the** sun
>   *Butterflies fluttered about in **the** sunshine.
>
>   The house, with its fresh coat of paint, looked lovely in **the** sunshine.
>
>   In the village square, people were milling about in **the** sunshine.*

But take into account what @FumbleFingers has mentioned:

*Sunshine (along with sunlight and daylight) are normally seen as "omnidirectional" (the light comes from the whole sky, not just the sun)*

and

*Google Books has no written instances of his back to the sunshine, whereas it claims About 141,000 results for what I consider the natural version: his back to the sun*

Maybe you should rephrase it using **the sun** instead of the sunshine.